# localhost works but ip does not tomcat

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, localhost

I am using Spring STS which uses the apache tomcat server,I create a dynamic web project and run it on the sever
With http://localhost:8080/webapp the application runs perfectly but when i use ip address it does not and gives 404 (ie:http://IpAddressOfMyMachine:8080/webapp.

Below is my server.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="${base.shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer"/>
    <Listener accessFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.access" address="127.0.0.1" authenticate="true" className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener" passwordFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.password" port="${base.jmx.port}" useSSL="false"/>
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Executor maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="50" name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="tomcat-http--"/>
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" deployXML="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
            <Context docBase="pcap" path="/webapp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:pcap"/></Host>
        </Engine>
        <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="${bio.http.port}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Can anyone please provide an idea which config files I need to change?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Ok, I don't know Mac, but on Windows, the most common reason is the Windows Firewall blocking access. Do you have some anti-virus/firewall that might be blocking?

Comment: Not always.As if that was the case in eclipse it shouldnt have worked.Also my REST service using the spring boot app runs fine with the ip address